# reduce() and Reduce() (upper and lowercase)

Tags: python, mpi

In my coursework my lectrure specifically recomends to use comm.reduce(lowercase) to solve a particluar problem, however all the referances to MPI reduce syntax have been Reduce(uppercase) as have all the examples ive found in the lecture notes and examples ive done myself so i dont know the precices syntax of the argument.

in my current code ive tried to base the syntax off the gather() command which gives me: "A = comm.reduce(x_local,MPI.SUM)" so i put it into this code to check it would work:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy as np

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()


x_local = 5*size
print("on rank:",rank," local value is: ",x_local)
A = np.zeros(size)
if rank == 0:
    A = comm.reduce(x_local,MPI.SUM)
    print(A)
```

however when i try to run this code in terminal it simply doesnt work, i will print any other rank than rank=0 fine but it will give no other error, no feedback, it just sits there for ever untill i press crtl+c. Ive left it there for about an hour while i did someting else and when i came back it was still doing the same thing. I can only assume that i have the syntax wrong but i dont know why python just spits out an error. Any help would be appreciated

(along with a link that does actually include both upper and lowercase instances of reduce and other mpi functions)

Comment: did you try running it with the reduce in capital? (full disclaimer, i know nothing about what's going on here). But hey, its your computer, and all the tools are in your hands, play around with it! I would suspect however that shouldn't there be something else that would need to happen? (without knowing anything here.) No idea, but it just seems all too, weirdly simple. maybe some critical first step?

Comment: yes ive been trying that but it doesnt like that all its sending is an integer, thats very common for MPI commands, the lowercase command is usually for arrays of values and not much more, while the uppercase commands deals with more complicated data transfers

Comment: more info to that: i get a tuple error as the Reduce() command expects at least a dimension of 2 (allowing for sending matricies and such) while reduce() uses just one dimension (deals with just a single 1D array).

Comment: `MPI_Reduce()` is a collective operation and as a direct consequence it must be invoked by all the ranks of the communicator. Your program likely hangs because only rank 0 is calling `MPI_Reduce()`

Comment: thank you, thats fixed it, after i had fixed all other errors numpy arrays, thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

Your issue has nothing to do with upper/lower-case.

Reduce, in whatever capitalization, is a collective operation. All ranks of the communicator must participate in calling the function.

Regarding upper/lower-case, this is specific for mpi4py. The upper-case variants use "memory buffers" while the lower-case variants can communicate python objects.

See also: https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#communicating-python-objects-and-array-data